# Which way should I use to compare the phase of a cosine function with a sine function?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

We represent the position of a particle in simple harmonic motion (SHM) as $$ x(t)=A \sin(\omega t).$$
If we want to compare its phase with another SHM whose equation is given in terms of a cosine function then we have to first convert them to the same trigonometric function.

My queston is whether I should write $\sin(\pi/2 + \omega t)$ or $\sin(\pi/2 - \omega t)$ to convert the sine into a cosine. Also can $x$ and $y$ be used interchangeably when writing the position equation?

Comment: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/class/waves is a  website based around fundamental physics concepts that might help you for more than just this question. Also Hyperphysics.com  is quite good.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Symmetry.2C_shifts.2C_and_periodicity . VTC because not about physics.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about physics but about trigonometry.

Comment: What does $y$ represent?  Why not use $z$? Those are just symbols which represent some concept. You must link the concept to the symbol for it to have any meaning in  a problem.

Comment: An argument for $\pi/2-\omega t$ may be that it's the same for $\sin\to\cos$ and $\cos\to\sin$, unlike the version with addition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more general way of writing the equation for the motion would be:

$$ x(t)=A \sin(\omega t + \phi) $$

where $\phi$ is the phase constant. You find the value of $\phi$ simply by looking to see what happens at time zero i.e.

$$ \sin(\phi) = \frac{x(0)}{A} $$

If someone else is using the equation:

$$ x(t)=A \cos(\omega t) $$

then $x(0) = A$ so $\phi = \arcsin(A/A) = \arcsin(1) = \pi/2$, and their equation in your terms would be:

$$ x(t)=A \sin\left(\omega t + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) $$